Show that $\left( \text{Lip} \left( \left[ a,b \right]~\mathbb{R} \right), \left\lVert \cdot \right\rVert \right)$ is complete.
Is my proof correct ?
Let $E=\text{Lip} \left( \left[ a,b \right],~\mathbb{R} \right)$ be the vector space of real Lipschitz functions on $\left[ a,b \right]$ for $\left( a,b \right) \in \mathbb{R}^2$ such that $a<b$. We define $\left\lVert \cdot \right\rVert$ as :
$$\forall f \in E, ~ \left\lVert f \right\rVert := \left\lVert f \right\rVert _{\infty} + \underset{\left( x,y \right) \in \left[ a,b \right]^2,~x \neq y}{\text{sup}} ~ \frac{\left| f(x)-f(y) \right|}{\left| x-y \right|}$$
Let $\left( f_n \right)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ be a Cauchy sequence of $\left( \text{Lip} \left( \left[ a,b \right]  \right), \left\lVert \cdot \right\rVert \right)$ and $\epsilon > 0$. It exists $N_{\epsilon} \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\forall (n,m) \in \mathbb{N}^2,~n \geqslant N_\epsilon$ and $m \geqslant N_\epsilon$ :
$$\epsilon > \left\lVert f_n - f_m \right\rVert = \left\lVert f_n - f_m \right\rVert _\infty +  \underset{\left( x,y \right) \in \left[ a,b \right]^2,~x \neq y}{\text{sup}} ~ \frac{\left| f_n(x)- f_n(y) +f_m (y) - f_m (x) \right|}{\left| x-y \right|}$$
$\forall x \in \left[a,b\right],~\left( f_n (x) \right)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is Cauchy in $\left( \mathbb{R}, \left| \cdot \right| \right)$ so it converges to a limit that we denote as $f(x)$.
\begin{align*}
 \forall (x,y) \in \left[ a,b \right]^2,~n \geqslant N_\epsilon ,~ m \geqslant N_\epsilon , \quad & \left| f_n(x)- f_n(y) +f_m (y) - f_m (x) \right| < \epsilon \left| x-y \right| \\
 & \Longrightarrow \left| f_n(x)- f_n(y) +f (y) - f(x) \right| < \epsilon \left| x-y \right|~\text{when $m \rightarrow + \infty$} \\
 & \Longrightarrow \left| f(x)- f(y) \right| < \epsilon \left| x-y \right| +  \left| f_n(x) -f_n(y) \right|
\end{align*}
This proves that $f \in E$. When $m \rightarrow + \infty$ and $n \geqslant N_\epsilon$ :
$$ \epsilon > \left\lVert f_n - f \right\rVert $$
The sequence $\left( f_n \right)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ does converge to $f \in E$ thus $\left( \text{Lip} \left( \left[ a,b \right]  \right), \left\lVert \cdot \right\rVert \right)$ is complete.
